Which ui component file is responsible for tier pricing in magento2
I need to find the file which is responsible for displaying tier prices for prodcuts in the admin panel

You can have a look at the file vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/AdvancedPricing.php, specifically within the getTierPriceStructure method.

AND ALSO where i need to change the code for savig these multi select options, basically which file is responsible for saving this customergroups options.

I changed it as multiselect but it will go as array, so where i need to change the code to make changes while saving that, which files will do that works
